# Is there excellent tutorial for how to use emacs?

Tags: emacs

I'm using it to write c/c++ code, where to get tutorial for beginner like me.

Comment: Google is your friend. http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/tour/

Comment: **Icicles** can help you learn Emacs in many ways. http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsNewbieWithIcicles

Answer (score 34):

From within emacs, type "C-h t" (control-h, t) to get an excellent interactive tutorial right from within emacs itself.

Comment: Pretty much the best tutorial I've seen yet.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to following the links/suggestions in the other answers, it may be very beneficial to become familiar with http://emacswiki.org -- everything from the [basics](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsNewbie) (including "how to use") to the most advanced arcane el files. This is also a good place to learn about the different modes and extensions available -- for instance, check out [c++-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CPlusPlusMode).

After all, half of emacs is getting the darn thing configured "how you like it" ;-)